# Cancel create model in collection. Fight with duplicate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

need create a handler, which not give create duplicate.

```
Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Model,
    initialize : function() {
        this.on('add', this.actionCreate, this);
    },
    actionCreate : function(model, collection, param) {
        // handler...
    }
});
collection = new Collection();
collection.add({ chanel : 'starladder' });
// Should not be created because the parameter 'chanel' already exists with this value
collection.add({ chanel : 'starladder});
```

I all ready try in handler write somsing like:

```
if( this.where({ chanel : model.get('chanel').length } ) { model.destroy(); }
```

but not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about that :)

First, you could simply do the check before the add! Then no need to worry about using Collection.remove() or Model.destroy()

```
if(!this.collection.findWhere({chanel: 'starladder'}))
  ...add...
```

As a side note, here you probably want Collection.remove() rather than Model.destroy() because your newly added Model doesn't seem to have an id, so there is no need for a possible server round-trip.

Second, your handler seems to have a few issues. .where() will return an array, so you need to do a check on the .length of the return value to see if it's > 0. Or you can use findWhere as above which will do the same as where but return the first value of that array, so you don't need to worry about doing a [0] to get to that model.

It's hard to tell what would be the best way to do what you want to achieve without more details, but it seems you are using *chanel* as a kind of unique ID...? so why not use the [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) property to let Backbone know that this is what defines your model in an unique way? Obviously, that only works if you don't real IDs to begin with...

If you need both *id* and *chanel* to be unique, then I'd just do a check before the add as you proposed and be on my way + obviously add the same uniqueness condition on the server side, because you never know + don't allow any way in the GUI for the user to pick the same value twice (remove values from select/dropdown/autocomplete, whatever).